# please help me understanding python object instantiation.

Tags: python, instantiation

I am not a programmer and I am trying to learn python at the moment. But I am a little confused with the object instantiation. I am thinking Class like a template and object is make(or instantiated) based on the template. **Doesn't that mean once object is created(eg. classinst1 = MyClass() ), change in template shouldn't affect what's in the object?**

In addition, the below code shows that I could change the class variable "common" but only if I haven't assign a new value to the "common" variable in the object. **If I assign a new value to "common" in my object (say classinst1.common = 99), then change my class variable "common" no longer affect classinst.common value????**

Can someone please clarify for me why the code below behave such way? Is it common to all OO language or just one of the quirky aspects of python?

===============

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     common = 10
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.myvar=3
...     def myfunction(self,arg1,arg2):
...             return self.myvar
... 
>>> classinst1 = MyClass()
>>> classinst1.myfunction(1,2)
3
>>> classinst2 = MyClass()
>>> classinst2.common
10
>>> classinst1.common
10
>>> MyClass.common = 50
>>> classinst1.common
50
>>> classinst2.common
50
>>> classinst1.common = 99
>>> classinst2.common
50
>>> classinst1.common
99
>>> MyClass.common = 7000
>>> classinst1.common
99
>>> classinst2.common
7000
```

Comment: its pretty common, if a variable in a class doesn't have self in front of it, it is common to all instances of the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the general idea of class declaration and instantiation right.  But the reason why the output in your example doesn't seem to make sense is that there are actually two variables called `common`.  The first is the class variable declared and instantiated at the top of your code, in the class declaration.  This is the only `common` for most of your example.

When you execute this line:

```
classinst1.common = 99
```

you are creating an object variable, a member of `classinst1`.  Since this has the same name as a class variable, it shadows or hides `MyClass.common`.  All further references to `classinst1.common` now refer to that object variable, while all references to `classinst2.common` continue to fall back to `MyClass.common` since there is no object variable called `common` that is a member of `classinst2`.

So when you execute:

```
MyClass.common = 7000
```

this changes `MyClass.common` but `classinst1.common` remains equal to 99.  And in the final lines of your example when you ask the interpreter for the values of `classinst1.common` and `classinst2.common`, the former refers to the `classinst1` object member variable `common` while the latter refers to the class variable `MyClass.common`.